# Adding a column in SQL using a JOIN

Tags: sql, join, insert

I'm sorry if this is a very basic question, I have searched for a solution but could not find an answer. I'm trying to copy a table, and then join three columns to the new table based on a common column.

The main table I'm working off of is master.alldata. I create a copy of it using:

```
select * into personal.alldata FROM master.alldata;
```

alldata has a PersonID column that serves as the master key.

I then want to add the three columns from another table, thirdparty.moredata. This table has a PersonID column, and three data columns. I create space in my main table using:

```
alter table personal.alldata
ADD data1 float;
```

(repeating this for data2 and data3)

Then finally I want to add data1, 2, and 3 to the master table, matching on the PersonID from both tables. I tried using this:

```
INSERT into personal.alldata (data1, data2, data3)
SELECT moredata.data1, mordata.data2, moredata.data3
FROM thirdparty.moredata
INNER JOIN personal.alldata
ON alldata.PersonID = moredata.personid;
```

The result still leaves null values in the data1, data2, and data3 columns. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to `UPDATE` the rows that get added or add new rows?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to `UPDATE` your data, not `INSERT` new data.  Depending on the RDBMS, the syntax is slightly different:

**MySQL:**

```
UPDATE personal.alldata ad
   JOIN thirdparty.moredata md ON ad.PersonID = md.PersonID
SET ad.data1 = md.data1
```

**SQL Server:**

```
UPDATE ad
SET ad.data1 = md.data1
FROM personal.alldata ad 
   JOIN thirdparty.moredata md ON ad.PersonID = md.PersonID
```